# How to select listbox at index by right-clicking?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a ContextFlyout in my form and I want the listbox to select the index where the mouse is upon right-click

Originally I thought I could take advantage of the RightTapped event so I created an event handler, but while filling out the method, I didn't see any way to translate the position of the mouse to an item in the listbox.

**RightTapped event**

```cs
private void SideMenu_RightClick(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e) {
    ListBox menu = (ListBox)sender;
    SideMenu.SelectedIndex = menu.IndexFromPoint(e.);
    menu.
}
```

I've looked through all the methods and properties but I can't seem to find what I need. I found a lot of solutions for WPF, but this is UWP and those methods do not exist on these UWP objects

Comment: Where and how are you handling the `RightTapped` event? Please include some sample code in your question.

Comment: @mm8 I went ahead and edited my post to include the event handler, it is attached to a listbox control named SideMenu

Comment: An easier approach would be to attache the event handler to the `ListBoxItem` or the root element in the `ItemTemplate`

Comment: @mm8 This is what I ended up doing. I think I was just tired from a long day of work yesterday and couldn't think. I was adding String's to my listbox which cannot have a ContextFlyout, Once I changed that to be ListBoxItems instead, the dominoes started to fall  quickly

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach would be to attach the event handler to the `ListBoxItem` or the root element in the `ItemTemplate`. You'll find an example of how you could do this [here](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2016/02/28/disabling-selection-of-some-items-in-a-uwp-listview/).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. Firstly, both my MenuFlyout and items for the listbox are generated programmatically.

**Creating MenuFlyout**

```cs
//this is a property in the class
internal MenuFlyout rightclick = new MenuFlyout();

//In Page's Constructor
this.InitializeComponent();
MenuFlyoutItem mfi = new MenuFlyoutItem();
mfi.Text = "Copy";
rightclick.Items.Add(mfi);
mfi = new MenuFlyoutItem();
mfi.Text = "Delete";
rightclick.Items.Add(mfi);
rightclick.Opened += rightclick_opened;  //run method when flyout is opened
```

**Method for the Opened event**

```cs
private void rightclick_opened(object sender, object e) {
    MenuFlyout mf = (MenuFlyout)sender;
    SideMenu.SelectedItem = mf.Target;    //makes the magic happen
}
```

**Instantiating ListBoxItems**

```cs
private void NewLocation(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    Location newLocation = new Location(); //custom class
    ListBoxItem nl = new ListBoxItem();    //creates empty ListBoxItem
    nl.Content = newLocation.objectName; //give listboxitem default name from the class constructor
    nl.ContextFlyout = rightclick;         //set contextflyout for item
    SideMenu.Items.Add(nl);                //add new item to listbox
    locations.Add(newLocation);            //add new object to "linked" list
    SideMenu.SelectedIndex = locations.Count - 1; //set current selected to new item
}
```